# Conv or regressions to generate newspapers clips coords

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I'm new to this community and to machine learning/deep learning so this question might be very basic or maybe I'm barking to the wrong tree.

I'm trying to automate a very manual process which is **newspaper clipping**. 
This process requires a person going through a newspaper in .PDF format and marking with some tools where each article is in every page of the newspaper. I end up having a file with **ordered coordinates** that frame every article's shape, location on the page, etc.

I have been studying convolutional neural networks for this since it looks like an image processing problem. However, I have seen that CNN are able to tell what's in the image without saying **where** it is.

I am about to working on the model and start training with all the data I have, however, something tells me that this is not the right approach or there's something missing, I don't see how it will be possible for the CNN to output the coordinates, considering that they need to be:

- in a certain order to delimit the article's shape
- accurate enough so it doesn't clip the articles incorrectly

If someone could point me in the right direction and give me some guidance + suggestions, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a fairly classic image segmentation problem, CNN-based architectures should be able to handle that. There's a bunch of different approaches though (predict bounding box coords, predict the area, predict a graph...) and I don't feel qualified enough to give you authoritative advice on which particular one to use.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @jkm I will look into the boundaries prediction approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ordered coordinates, the first thing that I think of is bounding-box regression. Two main algorithms in this area come to mind that might be useful:

1) [Faster R-CNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497?context=cs.CV): The main idea is to superimpose "anchors" (basically a grid of pre-defined rectangles) over the image, figure out which anchors are "interesting" (contain an object), and then perform bounding box regression on those rectangles. This is a *very* high-level overview — technical overview linked.

2) [YOLO](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf): The main idea here is to divide the image into a big grid. Each square in the grid is responsible for detecting **one** object only, and will output B bounding boxes and class-conditional probabilities (Pr of class C given object exists). Apply non-maximal suppression at test-time, and you have your predictions.

*Note: the limitations to YOLO that you'll often see (bad at fine-grained features, less accurate) will likely be less impactful on the newspaper article-detection case, since 1) usually articles fill rectangular areas, 2) such areas take up a large proportion of the page, and 3) it is unlikely that a single grid box will contain more than 1 article.*

Some quick words of caution though: **As with any neural net, your model is only as good as your data.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the notes, I will be taking a look at these approaches. Luckily, the data or training set is big enough and the quality of the data is very good.

Comment: Yep! Also, see if someone's already done something similar — don't reinvent the wheel unless you have to.

Comment: I was reasearching and looking for something similar but couldn't find anything that really captures the idea, found some related work but not exactly detecting these boxes. I'll keep looking and trying to adapt existing solutions. Thanks!